# Determine season from Date using lubridate in R

Tags: r, posixct, lubridate

I have a very big dataset with a `DateTime` Column containing POSIXct-Values. I need to determine the season (Winter - Summer) based on the `DateTime` column. I've created a function which works fine on a small dataset, but crashes when I use it on the large one. Can anybody see my mistake?

I've created 4 functions:

- 3 subfunctions so that I can do logical comparisons and selection
  using *apply functions
- 1 function to determine the season

Here are thefunctions:

```
require(lubridate)

# function for logical comparison (to be used in *apply)
greaterOrEqual <- function(x,y){
  ifelse(x >= y,T,F)
}

# function for logical comparison (to be used in *apply)
less <- function(x,y){
  ifelse(x < y,T,F)
}

# function for logical comparison (to be used in *apply)
selFromLogic <- function(VecLogic,VecValue){
  VecValue[VecLogic]
}

# Main Function to determine the season
getTwoSeasons <- function(input.date) {
  Winter1Start <- as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC")
  Winter1End <- as.POSIXct("2000-04-15 23:59:59", tz = "UTC")

  SummerStart <- Winter1End + 1
  SummerEnd <- as.POSIXct("2000-10-15 23:59:59", tz = "UTC")

  Winter2Start <- SummerEnd + 1
  Winter2End <- as.POSIXct("2000-12-31 00:00:00", tz = "UTC")

  year(input.date) <- year(Winter1Start)
  attr(input.date, "tzone") <- attr(Winter1Start, "tzone")

  SeasonStart <- c(Winter1Start,SummerStart,Winter2Start)
  SeasonsEnd <- c(Winter1End,SummerEnd,Winter2End)
  Season_names <- as.factor(c("WinterHalfYear","SummerHalfYear","WinterHalfYear"))

  Season_select <- sapply(SeasonStart, greaterOrEqual, x = input.date) & sapply(SeasonsEnd, less, x = input.date)
  Season_return <- apply(Season_select,MARGIN = 1,selFromLogic,VecValue = Season_names)

  return(Season_return)
}
```

And here's a way to test the function:

```
dates <- Sys.time() + seq(0,10000,10)
getTwoSeasons(dates)
```

I would be thankful for any help, this is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I packaged @Lars Arne Jordanger's much more elegant approach into a function:

```
getTwoSeasons <- function(input.date){
  numeric.date <- 100*month(input.date)+day(input.date)
  ## input Seasons upper limits in the form MMDD in the "break =" option:
  cuts <- base::cut(numeric.date, breaks = c(0,415,1015,1231)) 
  # rename the resulting groups (could've been done within cut(...levels=) if "Winter" wasn't double
  levels(cuts) <- c("Winter", "Summer","Winter")
  return(cuts)
}
```

Testing it on some sample data seems to work fine:

```
getTwoSeasons(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 12:00:00")+(0:365)*(60*60*24))
```

Answer (score 14):

And if you're interested in getting back **four** seasons, here's code to do that:

```
library(lubridate)
getSeason <- function(input.date){
  numeric.date <- 100*month(input.date)+day(input.date)
  ## input Seasons upper limits in the form MMDD in the "break =" option:
  cuts <- base::cut(numeric.date, breaks = c(0,319,0620,0921,1220,1231)) 
  # rename the resulting groups (could've been done within cut(...levels=) if "Winter" wasn't double
  levels(cuts) <- c("Winter","Spring","Summer","Fall","Winter")
  return(cuts)
}
```

Unit Test:

```
getSeason(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 12:00:00")+(0:365)*(60*60*24))
```

Answer (score 8):

For completeness, worth noting that `lubridate` now has a quarter (and a semester) function. `quarter` splits the year into fourths and `semester` into halves:

```
library(lubridate)

quarter(x, with_year = FALSE, fiscal_start = 1)
semester(x, with_year = FALSE)
```

For more, see: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.4/topics/quarter

Answer (score 2):

After several hours of debugging I've found my mistake, and it's quite absurd really:

If a season for a DateTimeValue was not found,  `apply` returned `list`-object instead of a `vector` (this was the case when the DateTime value equalled `2000-12-31 00:00:00`). Returning a list created an an overproportional increase in computation time and the described crashes. Here's a the fixed code:

```
# input date and return 2 season
getTwoSeasons <- function(input.date) {
  Winter1Start <- as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC")
  Winter1End <- as.POSIXct("2000-04-15 23:59:59", tz = "UTC")

  SummerStart <- Winter1End + 1
  SummerEnd <- as.POSIXct("2000-10-15 23:59:59", tz = "UTC")

  Winter2Start <- SummerEnd + 1
  Winter2End <- as.POSIXct("2001-01-01 00:00:01", tz = "UTC")

  SeasonStart <- c(Winter1Start,SummerStart,Winter2Start)
  SeasonsEnd <- c(Winter1End,SummerEnd,Winter2End)
  Season_names <- factor(c("WinterHalf","SummerHalf","WinterHalf"))

  year(input.date) <- year(Winter1Start)
  attr(input.date, "tzone") <- attr(Winter1Start, "tzone")

  Season_selectStart <- vapply(X = SeasonStart,function(x,y){x <= input.date},FUN.VALUE = logical(length(input.date)),y = input.date)
  Season_selectEnd   <- vapply(X = SeasonsEnd,function(x,y){x > input.date},FUN.VALUE = logical(length(input.date)),y = input.date)
  Season_selectBoth  <- Season_selectStart & Season_selectEnd
  Season_return <- apply(Season_selectBoth,MARGIN = 1,function(x,y){y[x]}, y = Season_names)
  return(Season_return)
}
```

The "sub"-functions are now integrated in the main function and two `sapply` functions replaced with `vapply`.

PS: There is still an issue with the timezone, since c() strips the timezone away. I'll update the code when I fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The following strategy can also be used: The basic observation is that
`substr` can extract the month and day information we need in order to
decide if it's summer or winter.  The idea is then to convert this to
numbers of the form *month.date*, and the test for being summer then
boils down to having a number larger than 4.15 but smaller than 10.16.

The example below shows how this can be done when a vector of dates
first are transformed into the alternative presentation described
above, and then a vector that tells if it is summer "TRUE" or winter
"FALSE" will be created based on this.

```
DateTime <- as.POSIXct(x  = "2000-01-01 00:00:00",
                       tz = "UTC") +
    (0:1000)*(60*60*24)

DateTime_2 <- as.numeric(paste(
    substr(x = DateTime,
           start = 6,
           stop = 7),
    substr(x = DateTime,
           start = 9,
           stop = 10),
    sep = "."))

.season <- (DateTime_2 > 4.15) & (DateTime_2 < 10.16)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the POSXlt instead of POSXct.**

I made my own function depending on the definition of seasons that I am using. I created vectors named **normal** for a non-leap year and **leap** for leap year with each season name repeated the no. of times it appears starting from Jan 1. And created the following function.

```
SEASON <- function(datee){
  
  datee <- as.POSIXlt(datee)
  season <- vector()
  normal <- rep(c("Winter","Spring","Summer","Monsoon","Autumn","Winter"), c(46,44,91,77,76,31))
  leap <- rep(c("Winter","Spring","Summer","Monsoon","Autumn","Winter"), c(46,45,91,77,76,31))

  
  if(leap_year(year(datee)) == FALSE){
    season <- normal[datee$yday+1]
  } else {
    season <- leap[datee$yday+1]
  }
  return(season)
}
```

Let's put it to test for some dataset.

```
Dates <- seq(as.POSIXct("2000-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2010-01-01"), by= "day")
sapply(Dates, SEASON)
```

It works.