# How can I create a new column for seasons based on date ranges?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, character

```
#make a horrible data frame:

ottawadates <- as.Date(c("2016-08-04", "2016-09-03", "2016-02-15", "2016-03-29, "2016-09-27"))
othervariable <- c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6)
df = data.frame(othervariable, ottawadates)
```

Okay, so all I'd like to do is create a new field called 'seasons'. I would like to use ranges of dates to indicate which dates belong to corresponding seasons. Just to be clear, my actual data set has the dates in a proper date format so I'm guessing indexing date ranges is fairly straightforward.

i.e. December 21st - March 19th is WINTER.
     March 20 - June 20th is SPRING
     June 21st - September 21 is SUMMER
     September 23 - December 20 is FALL

I feel like this is a for loop job, but I'm too novice to know how to go about it.

Thanks. I appreciate it!

Comment: You'll get a better answer if your example includes the data in the same format as your data. So if your data set uses dates, use dates in your example.

Comment: seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502140/determine-season-from-date-using-lubridate-in-r

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500114/find-which-season-a-particular-date-belongs-to

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I updated the sample data so it assumes date format.

As for the links, thanks. I'm just confused how to use these chunks so that they iterate through my own dataset and add the right season to the corresponding row in the new 'seasons' column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lubridate` and `ifelse` to find season based on date range. Assuming seasons as `Winter` and `Other season` one approach could be as:

```
#data
ottawadates <- as.Date(c("2016-08-04", "2016-09-03", "2016-02-15"))
othervariable <- c(1, 2, 4)
df = data.frame(othervariable, ottawadates)

library(lubridate)
df$ottawadates <- ymd(df$ottawadates)

#Evaluate season
df$season <- ifelse((month(df$ottawadates) %in% c(1, 2)) |
                  (month(df$ottawadates) == 12L & day(df$ottawadates) >= 21L) |
                  (month(df$ottawadates) == 3L & day(df$ottawadates) <= 19L),
                  "Winter", 
                  ifelse( (month(df$ottawadates) %in% c(4, 5)) |
                  (month(df$ottawadates) == 3L & day(df$ottawadates) >= 20L) |
                  (month(df$ottawadates) == 6L & day(df$ottawadates) <= 20L),
                   "Spring",
                   ifelse( (month(df$ottawadates) %in% c(7, 8)) |
                           (month(df$ottawadates) == 6L & day(df$ottawadates) >= 21L) |
                           (month(df$ottawadates) == 9L & day(df$ottawadates) <= 21L),
                           "Summer", "Fall")))


df
#  othervariable ottawadates  season
#1             1  2016-08-04  Summer
#2             2  2016-09-03  Summer
#3             4  2016-02-15  Winter
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I use Spring and such? Just more ifelse statements? How would you write that?

Comment: @hmnoidk Please add range for spring and I can modify my answer. Basically same way you have to add nested `ifelse`.

Comment: Thanks again. i added the date ranges.

Comment: @hmnoidk Have a look.