# R: Customizing seasons for windRose plot in Openair

Tags: r, datetime, openair, rose-plot

I am trying to plot a wind rose plot of a site using `openair` package in `R`. The code snippet is:

`windRose(df, type = "season", paddle = F, key.position = "right")`
and the plot is: [image]

We know, this package `openair` considers seasons **DJF** as winter,  **MAM** as spring and so on. However, in this region another categorization for seasons is commonly used as follows:

- **winter:** Dec Jan Feb
- **Pre-monsoon:** Mar Apr May Jun15 (i.e. *till 15th of June*)
- **Monsoon:** 15Jun Jul Aug Sep (i.e. from 15th of June)
- **Post-monsoon:** Oct Nov.

I am new in R, hence finding difficulty to plot the wind rose with the later categorization and putting the titles accordingly. I would highly appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Function `windRose` has an argument "type" which accepts a custom character or factor vector to facet (and label) the plot by.

1. add a column for your custom season, e.g. "my_custom_season"
2. make this column contain the corresponding season for each row ("winter", "pre-monsoon" etc.)
3. call `windRose(your_data,...,type="my_custom_season")`

Comment: thanks for the reply. But my main problem here is first to select the data according to the new seasons. Like for premonsoon I want to select data between Mar, Apr, May and till June 15 and so on. Can you please provide any help on this?

Comment: For one possibility to convert dates into custom intervals (e.g. seasons) please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39894310/18309711 . That solution requires an extra package ({lubridate}) for convenient handling of various date and time types.